# I am making an autofill type bot and i have run into a little bit of a problem

Tags: python

I want to make a while loop that checks if a certain error message is printed on the screen. I check to see if a current name is available to take and if it isn't I do something and if it is I do something different.
I want it to say something like while the screen says ''Username has already been taken'' it will do one thing and if it does not come up on the screen it just skips the while loop.

When the error message is triggered:

```
<p id="username_notification" class="notification" style="">Username has already been taken</p>
```

Also the xpath of it in case it is needed:

```
//*[@id="username_notification"]
```

Also probably not needed but here is the message if the username is okay to use:

```
<p id="username_notification" class="notification" style="">Available! 
</p>
```

And xpath for that:

```
//*[@id="username_notification"]
```

## Its also probably obvious but I'm new to python and coding in general. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume your script is entering a username into a web site that either checks availability passively, or requires the username to be actively submitted by your script to be checked. Either way, I assume your script is managing that requirement.

I assume you want a while loop to test until either one of the `<p>` elements with id="username_notification" to manage any lag between the script entering a username and the server response when availability is checked.

I assume the `<p>` element is going to be inserted into the DOM at a predictable location and will always have the id="username_notification".

So you want a `while True` loop which scrapes the page, checks for one or other of the `<p>` elements, when it finds one it breaks conditionally depending on which one it finds to discrete functions, e.g., on "Username has already been taken" re-enter a new username, or on "Available!" do something else...

But I'm not sure what your problem is in implementing it. What have you tried?